# Calculate the Lie derivative using definition

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, lie-derivative

**Definition:** *If $X$ and $Y$ are vector fields on a smooth manifold $M$, the Lie derivative of $Y$ in the direction of $X$ is the vector field $$
\mathcal{L}_X Y := \frac{d}{dt}\bigg\vert_{t=0}(F^X_{-t})_\ast Y.
$$ Here $F^X$ denotes the flow of $X$.*

Using this definition, calculate the Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_X Y$ where $X = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $Y = x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ (here $x,y$ are the standard coordinates on $\Bbb{R}^2$).

---

---

**My attempt:**

A previous exercise asked to calculate this via the Lie bracket, to which I found that $[X,Y] = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, so I know the Lie derivative must equal this as well.

I calculated the flow of $X$ as being $F^X: \Bbb{R}^2 \times \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}: ((x,y),t) \mapsto (x+t,y)$. Hence at a time$-t$ we get $F^X_{-t} = (x-t,y)$. But when I calculate the derivative of this map, I just get that the derivative, $(F^X_{-t})_\ast = \operatorname{Id}$. But this is independent of $t$, so that would mean $\mathcal{L}_X Y = 0$, which is not the correct answer.

Where did I go wrong here? Is the flow correct? What about the derivative? Am I interpreting the notation incorrectly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, your Lie bracket is off by a sign. Next, write out the derivative computation carefully. You need to evaluate $Y$ at $F_t(x,y)$ and then act by $(F_{-t})_*$.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Apparently the vector fields $X$ and $Y$ switched places in this exercise as opposed to the previous where I calculated the bracket. I'll edit that part

Comment: As for the second part of your comment, I don't really know what you mean. I have a really poor understanding of differential geometry. Could you put this in an answer possibly?

Answer (score 2):

Write down
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(F_{-t})_*(Y(F_t(x,y)))-Y(x,y)}t=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(F_{-t})_*((x+t)\partial/\partial x_2)-(x\,\partial/\partial x_2)}t.$$

Comment: Why do we evaluate $Y$ in $F_t(x,y)$? I get that this should be the limit definition of a derivative, but don't understand it fully. (By the way, I changed $x_1$ and $x_2$ in my question to $x$ and $y$ to be more compatible with my flow function, since I kinda mixed the two notations)

Comment: Because the whole point is to compare tangent vectors at $F_t(x,y)$ with tangent vectors at $(x,y)$. You must move the former to $(x,y)$ to add/subtract.

Comment: I looked at my theory again, and now understand why we have $Y(F_t(x,y))$. It has to do with the fact that $F_\ast(Y)$ actually denotes the pushforward of $Y$ by $F$, which then satisfies $(F_\ast)_p(Y_p) = Y(F(p))$ for all $p\in M$.

What I now don't understand is why you don't have $(x-t)\partial/\partial y$ in the fraction, but instead have $x+t$. I thought you evaluated $Y$ in $F_{-t}^X(x,y) = (x-t,y)$?

Comment: No, your equation on pushforward is incorrect. The derivative of $f\colon M\to N$ at $p$ maps $T_pM$ to $T_{f(p)}N$. In this case, the derivative (or pushforward) of $F_{-t}$ maps $T_{F_t(x,y)}\Bbb R^2$ to $T_{(x,y)}\Bbb R^2$ because $F_{-t}\big(F_t(x,y)\big)=(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X,Y$ be vector fields on $M$. We compute (in general) that $\mathcal L_XY=[X,Y]$, where $[X,Y]=XY-YX$ is the Lie bracket of them.

In your case you can just put $X =\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $Y = x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ and get the desired result.

Here is the proof:

Suppose $f\in C^\infty(M),\,p\in M.$ (i.e., smooth function on $M$ that maps to $\mathbb R$)

Note that by definition of vector field, we should have

$$((F^X_{-t})_*Y)_pf=Y_{F^X_t(p)}(f\circ F^X_{-t})=(F^X_{t})^*(Y(f\circ F^X_{-t}))(p)$$

To be more precise, $(Y(f\circ F^X_{-t}))$ is a smooth map and pullback of it under $(F^X_{t})$ is just the usual composition of two maps, which corresponds to the middle one.

As for the first equality, actually this could be viewed as definition of pushforward of vector fields, since we **defined** that, for a diffeomorphism $F:N\to M,$ the pushforward of a tangent vector $X_p \in T_pN$ is given by $ F_{*,p}:T_pN \rightarrow T_{F(p)}M,$ where
$$F_*X\colon q\mapsto(F_*X)_q = dF_{F^{-1}(q)}(X_{F^{-1}(q)}).$$
In our case $F^X_{-t}$ is a flow along $X$ so it is a (local) diffeomorphism by definition, and $q=p$, corresponding to our notations.

(I think this is the desired answer to what you confused so far, but I will write down the rest of proof for those who may have the same question.)

We have
\begin{align}
(\mathcal L_XY)f&=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{((F^X_{-t})_*)Y)f-Yf}{t}\\
&=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{(F^X_{t})^*(Y(f\circ F^X_{-t}))-Yf}{t}\\
&=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{(F^X_{t})^*(Y(f\circ F^X_{-t}))-Y(f\circ F^X_{-t})+Y(f\circ F^X_{-t})-Yf}{t}\\
&=X(Yf)-Y(Xf)=[X,Y]f.
\end{align}
Note that, as we just know, $(Y(f\circ F^X_{-t}))$ is a smooth map, may write it as $G$ for convenience, then we have
$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{(F^X_{t})^*(Y(f\circ F^X_{-t}))-Y(f\circ F^X_{-t})}{t}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{(F^X_{t})^*G-G}{t}=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg\vert_{t=0}G\circ(F^X_{t})$$
which becomes $dG\left(\frac{d}{dt}\bigg\vert_{t=0}F^X_{t}\right)=dG(X)=XG,$ and the other term is similar, by using chain rule.